# using sql server index to better performance

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables (UserLog and UserInfo) on which there is a nonclustered index on User_UID column which is a unique identifier.

I have a lot of select queries that join these 2 tables on the User_UID column.

There is no cluster index on these tables; so to improve read performance I decide to create, a new column User_ID and then create a cluster index on this column, on each table.

I then tested the new architecture and I obtained great results since I decrease the logical read on both tables since the query optimiser don't use anymore a RID lookup in order to retreive the remain informations. Instead it use only the cluster index seek.

I obtained these good results only when the pages are already in memory cache, i.e. after 2 executions. However if I clean the cache (`dbcc dropcleanbuffers`) the first execution of the select query give also less logical read but the elapsed time is greater than it was when I execute the same query whith the old architecture (without the clustered index) just after cleaning cache.

So my question is why the elapsed time with the new architecture increase after cleaning the cache. Is it because in the first execution all data have to go into the memory cache and since in the cluster index we have more data than in non cluster index it takes more time??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Regardless, you should have a clustered index on your table.  If you don't, you have a heap and that requires scans through the leaf level of the table.  With a clustered index, your table is now sorted into a b-tree that is used for navigation to the leaf level and is more efficient.

By blowing out the the buffer, whether you have a seek on a clustered index or scan on a heap, the pages will be pulled from disk and that takes time.